# Is nested partition possible in BigQuery?

Tags: json, csv, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, cloud

I wanted to create nested partition table in Bigquery - year,month,day. Is this possible ? if not any other way I can do it better?

Comment: I'm not sure why you would need to. What's the intended outcome that you're trying to achieve?

Comment: The closest I can think of is hive partitioning - Support for [loading](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/hive-partitioned-loads-gcs) and [querying](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/hive-partitioned-queries-gcs) externally partitioned data that is stored on Cloud Storage using a default **hive partitioning layout** is now Generally Available. The data must be in Avro, Parquet, ORC, CSV, or JSON format.

Comment: Can you elaborate more and share more context about your use case and table example?